# Compile assembly in runtime and save dll in a folder

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime, .net-assembly

This is my code:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false;
CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);

if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
    foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors )
    {
        errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n", 
               error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
    }
    throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
}
else
{
    return results.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

How do I save the created dll to my own specific folder? When I debug, somehow the assembly location is at 'AppData/Local/Temp/' folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `OutputAssembly` property of `CompilerParameters` to sets the name (path) of the output assembly. 
From your example:

```
...
CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false;

compilerparams.OutputAssembly = "OutputAssembly.dll";

CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
...
```

Comment: I will accept this answer, though is still end up in 'AppData/Local/Temp/'.

Comment: @dausdashsan That's strange. I've tested the code, and it does put the assembly in wherever the `OutputAssembly` property points to. The only way the assembly end up in `AppData/Local/Temp/` is when an empty/ null string is passed to the `OutputAssembly` property.

Answer (score 3):

With OutputAssembly property you can specify just the assembly name. The Assembly will be created in current directory.
If you need to specify the full path you have to set the compiler options string in this way:

```
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
 parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
 parameters.CompilerOptions = " /out:C:\\Temp\\" + outputAssemblyFile;
```

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx), many options can be set in this property.
If you set CompilerOptions then OutputAssembly property will be ignored.

I hope this can help.